# AngularJS read JSON file $http service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I am having trouble to read data from my test.json file with the #http service. I am running all in a xampp localhost, can't really figure what is happening, here is the js code. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
            $http.get('test.json').success(function(response){
                $scope.myData = response;
            });
        }]);
</script>
```

EDIT: That is the json file: 
`[{"id":"1","name":"John"},
 {"id":"2","name":"Paul"},]`

And this is the rest of the html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in myData">
        {{data.id}}
        {{data.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you got error in your console ?

Comment: Check you js console and tell us what is error or msg is printing there.

Comment: Where is the test.json? Are you parsing the response which is json?

Comment: this code should not make any trouble. please post your full code.

Comment: I've got no errors showing up in the console. I've got two files in a folder one is the test.json and the other is the index.php file.

Answer (score -1):

The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
            $http.get('test.json').then(function(response){
                $scope.myData = response;
            });
        }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try and format your data before passing to scope with the angular.fromJson api.

try this

```
$scope.myData = angular.fromJson(response);
```

instead of

```
$scope.myData = response;
```

and remember you should resolve with .then not success hope it helps.

Comment: Just tried using angular.fromJson, and now the console shows a 404 error.

Comment: Never mind I had the wrong name that's why the 404 happend, but still got the same problem. No errors in the console too.